# Vue and JSX, how do I get them working together

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsx

I've got a simple JSX component that I can't seem to get working in Vue:

```
<script>

export default {
  props: {
    level: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  render: function (createElement) {
    return <div>YEA</div>;
  },
};

</script>
```

vue --version

> 3.12.1

I've read that JSX is meant to work out of the box with CLI3.x.

This is the error I get:

```
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                         9:50:26 am

 error  in ./src/components/FormComponents.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:11)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   },
|   render: function (createElement) {
>     return <div>YEA</div>;
|   },
| };

 @ ./src/components/FormComponents.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-231 1:247-250 1:252-480 1:252-480
 @ ./src/components/FormComponents.vue
 @ ./src/components/globals.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.148:3000/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

The offical documentation (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) sent me here:
https://github.com/vuejs/jsx

But following the install instructions there made no change.

How do I get JSX working with Vue?

Comment: You'd better create an issue on their repo if you can't find one similar on there.